# Coming with a procedure to generate an array with special properties

Tags: algorithm, pseudocode

I have an array of size n. Each element can hold any integer as long as the following properties holds:

```
1) All elements are non-negative
2) sum(array[0,i+1])<i for 0<=i<n 
3) sum(array)=n-1
```

Let's call such an array a bucket.

I need to come up with a procedure that will generate the next bucket.

We can assume the first bucket is `{0,0,0...n-1}`

Example: For `n=5`, some possible combinations are

```
[0 0 0 0 4]    
[0 0 0 1 3]    
[0 0 0 2 2]    
[0 0 0 3 1]    
[0 0 1 2 1]    
[0 0 2 1 1]    
[0 1 1 1 1]    
[0 1 0 0 3]    
[0 1 1 0 2]
```

I'm having trouble coming up with a procedure that hits all the possible combinations. Any hints/tips? (Note I want to generate the next bucket. I'm not looking to print out all possible buckets at once)

Comment: Do you want to generate all the permutations, for suppose n=5. And then in the next bucket all those permutations can live which were not part of the first bucket?

Comment: This isn't a homework problem. Whatever I come up  with I can never get something like [0 1 1 0 2]  to appear in the list. I can only get the combinations that are in non-decreasing order.

Comment: Homework or not, without code this is not a question for SO. Hint: grab some paper and make all possible lists for n=3. Observe what you are doing. If you don't get the algorithm then, make an exhaustive set of lists for n=4.

Comment: why do you want 'some' combinations and not all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a simple backtracking procedure. The idea is to keep track of the current `sum` and the current index `i`.  This would allow you to express the required constrains.

```
n = 5
a = [0] * n


def backtrack(i, sum):
    if i > 0 and sum > i-1:
        return
    if i == n:
        if sum == n-1:
            print(a)
        return
    for e in range(n-sum):
        a[i] = e
        backtrack(i + 1, sum+e)

backtrack(0, 0)
```

[test run](https://ideone.com/9VOqTO)